# Powermockito, JUnit and EclEmma debugging dosen't work

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, powermock

I want to use Powermockito, JUnit and EclEmma. First I had the problem, that EclEmma couldn't track the coverage, because of the PowermockRunner. I switched to the JUnit Rule of PowerMock. Now the coverage tracking is working. But now I have the problem, that I can't debug in Eclipse. Sometimes Eclipse shows the "Unable to insert breakpoint Absent Line Number Information" Error, but most the breakpoints are just ignored.

Here a example test:

```
@PrepareForTest({ Slf4jLoggerAdapter.class, LoggerFactory.class })
public class Slf4jLoggerAdapterTest
{
    /**
     * JUnit Rule
     */
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    /**
     * Test Debug Functions
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testDebug() throws Exception
    {
        LoggerFactory factory = mock(LoggerFactory.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        Mockito.when(LoggerFactory.getInstance()).thenReturn(factory);

        Mockito.when(factory.getLoggerLevel()).thenReturn(LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

        Slf4jLoggerAdapter la = PowerMockito.spy(new Slf4jLoggerAdapter("Test"));

        Marker marker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("testDebug");

        IOException exception = new IOException("Test");

        la.debug("Testmessage");
        verify(factory).debug(null, "Testmessage", null);

        la.debug(marker, "Testmessage");
        verify(factory).debug(marker, "Testmessage", null);

        la.debug("Testmessage {}", "Test");
        verify(factory).log(LoggerLevel.DEBUG, null, "Testmessage Test", null);

        la.debug("Testmessage {} {}", "Test", "Test");
        verify(factory).log(LoggerLevel.DEBUG, null, "Testmessage Test Test", null);

        la.debug("Testmessage", exception);
        verify(factory).debug(null, "Testmessage", exception);

        la.debug(marker, "Testmessage {}", "Test");
        verify(factory).log(LoggerLevel.DEBUG, marker, "Testmessage Test", null);

        la.debug(marker, "Testmessage {} {}", "Test", "Test");
        verify(factory).log(LoggerLevel.DEBUG, marker, "Testmessage Test Test", null);

        assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.valueOf(la.isDebugEnabled()));
        assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.valueOf(la.isDebugEnabled(marker)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, are you able to debug if you use the older "PowerMockRunner" strategy, even though you lose eclemma coverage info?  Also, are breakpoints not working in all classes, or just the test class, or just the CUT (class under test), or what?

Comment: 1) I was able to debug with the PowerMockRunner. 2) it doesn't with test class and the CUT. 3) Other classes working well. Sorry for the wait, I wanted to be sure and tested it

Comment: Ok. I don't have an answer.  If you don't get results here, try on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/powermock . I'd like to know the answer myself. :)

Comment: In my experience it is not possible to debug test classes that use PowerMockito to mock static method calls. I'd love to see a solution to this

Comment: @schnawel007 If the breakpoint is in one of the classes you are `@PrepareForTest` I believe that manipulates the way the class is loaded and the line numbers are not included.